# Excel - Track usage by time

Tags: excel

I have a table that shows datetime in second increments, location and true/false value (VPN).  I would like to graph usage by time and location - ie:  How many locations between 6-7, 7-8, etc.

Here is a short sample of the data.  How can I subtotal time and location?

```
         DATE               LOC     VPN
19 Jun 2012 3:07:40 AM MST  TX30    1
19 Jun 2012 4:58:33 AM MST  TX30    1
19 Jun 2012 5:02:57 AM MST  AZ50    1
19 Jun 2012 5:06:17 AM MST  TX30    1
19 Jun 2012 5:06:38 AM MST  TX30    1
19 Jun 2012 5:07:01 AM MST  ZBR20   0
19 Jun 2012 5:08:24 AM MST  TX30    1
19 Jun 2012 5:08:26 AM MST  ZIL05   0
19 Jun 2012 5:09:26 AM MST  AZ50    1
19 Jun 2012 5:10:18 AM MST  TX30    0
19 Jun 2012 5:11:44 AM MST  ZCZ01   0
```

Comment: Is all this information in one cell? Can you please show the breakdown of rows and columns?

Comment: I added column headings. Right now I am building a new column that has linear progression of hours and will add data filter to each row.  I was just wondering if there might be an easier alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For number of locations, assuming that data is in columns A-C:

Excel 2007+:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&(DATE(2012,6,19)+TIME(5,0,0)),A:A,"<"&(DATE(2012,6,19)+TIME(6,0,0)))
```

Earlier versions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A100>=(DATE(2012,6,19)+TIME(5,0,0))),--(A2:A100<(DATE(2012,6,19)+TIME(6,0,0))))
```